# Is one of $k+1^2,$ $k+2^2,$ ..., $k+N^2$ always prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that the Bunyakovsky conjecture is still open, so we can't prove that there exist primes of the form $n^2+k$ for a given $k$. But suppose that they do: is the least $n$ such that $n^2+k$ is prime bounded? This seems crazy, but I can't disprove it.

More formally:

> Is there an integer $N$ such that, for all positive integers $k$, either there are no primes of the form $n^2+k$ or one of $k+1^2, k+2^2,\ldots k+N^2$ is prime?

(Note that $x^2+k$ is irreducible unless $k=-m^2$ for some integer $m$.)

Comment: Any prime has the form $n^2 + k$ for some $n, k \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$. For the benefit of future readers of your question, can you please clarify the introductory sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $k = (N+1)!-1$, $k+n^2$ is divisible by $n+1$ for $n=1\ldots N$.

Comment: Thanks -- I should have been able to think of this!